# group of JList's? to single selection just one

Tags: java, swing

I have 6 JList and I want to make only 1 Jlist selectable, actually i'm doing this  inside of every JList MouseClicked event.

```
if (this.isSelected) {
 Jlist2.clearSelection();
 Jlist3.clearSelection();
 Jlist4.clearSelection();
 Jlist5.clearSelection();
 Jlist6.clearSelection();
}
```

all the JList are inside a BoxLayout, is there a way to make a group or another approch for this?

Comment: You only want one to be selected at a time or change the selection when the focus/selection changes for a different one?

Comment: I want to change the focus/selection to the JList that is clicked, for example: 1 item is selected in JList1 and I click on a JList6 item, so, the selection on JList1 must be cleared

Comment: Add the same `ListSelectionChangeListener` to all the `JList`'s, passing it a array or `List` of the `JList`s you want it to mange.  When the `valueChanged` event is triggered, loop through the list of `JList`s, where the source of the event is not the the same as the element in the lists, clear them.  This will require to ignore events that a triggered by you changing the selection, to which you can use a simple boolean flag

Comment: doing that way, and debugging that event and loop trigger a lot, it will not reduce the performance of the application?, or maybe because I dont get the last part of the paragraph this: "This will require to ignore events that a triggered by you changing the selection, to which you can use a simple boolean flag". i'm just looping the array of JList inside every ListSelectionListener and clearing the selection if is not the source

Comment: Each selection change will cause at least two to three events.  You can check `getValueIsAdjusting` to see when it's `false` and perform you desired actions then.  Remember, each time you call `clear`, it will trigger these events again for the list you modified, so you will end up clearing the selection for ALL the lists...